# Copy Row X amount of times based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

The macro copies and pastes the values of a row X amount of times based on a cell value in `M2`. It pastes the exact numbers over and over. Is there a way to change it so that numbers will ascend as they are copied down?

E.g. if `A2` contains "hello 3", after running the macro `A3` will contain "hello 4", `A4` will contain "hello 5".

```
Sub Sample()
Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
Dim lRow_I As Long, lRow_O As Long, i As Long, j As Long

'~~> Set your input and output sheets
Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

'~~> Output row
lRow_O = wsO.Range("A" & wsO.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

With wsI
    '~~> Get last row of input sheet
    lRow_I = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> Loop through the rows
    For i = 2 To lRow_I
        '~~> This will loop the number of time required
        '~~> i.e the number present in cell M
        For j = 1 To Val(Trim(.Range("M" & i).Value))
            '~~> This copies
            .Rows(i).Copy wsO.Rows(lRow_O)
            '~~> Get the next output row
            lRow_O = wsO.Range("A" & wsO.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Example of how input screen and output screen should look:

[image: Input]

Example of how output screen should look:

[image: Output]

Comment: .cells(lRow_O,1).value=.cells(lRow_O,1).value+1 something like that after the copy

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately I don't think this will work for me because not all cells are numeric values,updating the post now.

Comment: Cells(lRow_O-1, 1).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(lRow_O-1, 1), Cells(lRow_O, 1)), Type:=xlFillDefault   something like that for those types

Answer (score 0):

Actually no need for j loop if you use resize method.

```
Sub Sample()
Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet, lCounter As Long
Dim lRow_I As Long, lRow_O As Long, i As Long

Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

With wsI
    lCounter = Val(Trim(.Range("M" & i).Value))
    lRow_I = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lRow_I
        lRow_O = wsO.Range("A" & wsO.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        .Rows(i).Copy wsO.Rows(lRow_O).Resize(lCounter)
    Next i

End With
```

Comment: I don't think that way will increment the counter.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but Nathan_Sav is right, this doesn't increment the counter

Comment: Yes surely it wont increment the counter of the text value.  I just posted it to avoid j loop for speeder processing of code.

Comment: Use a combination of this and mine, use my lines after this, and use lcounter to set the auto filled range, rather than orow + 1 etc

Answer (score 0):

I upgrade my solution to have the "counter" incremented

```
Sub Sample()
Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
Dim lRow_I As Long, lRow_O As Long, i As Long, nRowsToPaste As Long
Dim rngToCopy As Range, rngToPaste As Range

'~~> Set your input and output sheets
Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetI")
Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetO") '<=== I made it different that wsI

'~~> Output row
lRow_O = wsO.Range("A" & wsO.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
With wsI
    '~~> Get last row of input sheet
    lRow_I = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row

    '~~> Loop through the rows
    For i = 2 To lRow_I
        nRowsToPaste = val(Trim(.Range("M" & i).Value)) '<== set number of rows to be pasted

        Set rngToCopy = .Range(.Cells(i, 1), .Cells(i, wsI.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)) '<== set range to be copied
        Set rngToPaste = wsO.Rows(lRow_O).Resize(1, rngToCopy.Columns.Count)             '<== set 1st row of the range to be pasted

        rngToCopy.Copy rngToPaste      '<== copy&paste the 1st row in wsO sheet                                                        '<== copy and paste the 1st row
        Call Prefix(rngToPaste) '<== differentiate each single cell of pasted range by means of adding a different prefix. this will subsequently have autofill method work on cells with originally the same value as well

        With rngToPaste
            .AutoFill .Resize(nRowsToPaste + 1) ' <== fill all rows exploiting AutoFill method, which will work on every column being their 1st row different from each other
            .Resize(nRowsToPaste + 1).Replace What:="%%*%%", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart '<== remove prefix
        End With

        lRow_O = lRow_O + nRowsToPaste + 1 '<== GET the next output row

    Next i

End With
End Sub

Sub Prefix(rng As Range)
Dim j As Long
With rng
    For j = 1 To .Columns.Count
        .Cells(1, j).Value = "%%" & j & "%%" & .Cells(1, j).Value
    Next j
End With
End Sub
```

where it eliminates the need of the inner j-loop and simply upgrades the lRow_O

Comment: Sixsthsense posted nearly the same solution while I was writing mine. but he placed his "lCounter" variablle outside the "i-loop" so that the number of pasted rows is always the same. which I think is not what Phlosef wanted

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your help with this, but it seems to have the same problem of not incrementing the counter though.

Comment: "lRow_O = lRow_O + nRowsToPaste"  is the increment statement.   it does increment as long as "nRowsToPaste" is >0.   Maybe its setting results in "0" due to what comes out of "val(Trim(.Range("M" & i).Value))" i.e. what is there in ".Range("M" & i).Value".

Comment: Hi, what I mean is that I am still left with the same numbers being pasted over and over again e.g. "hello 1" is repeated in each row rather than graduating to "hello 2", "hello 3", "hello 4" in each subsequent row. Do I need to use AutoFill perhaps?

Comment: please add a shot of the input sheet and of the output sheet as it should result after macro run