# Copy and paste rows x times based if x="cell value"

Tags: excel, vba

copy rows x-times and paste in new sheet x-amount of Rows. Then change the cell value of Col "S" to "1 of x", "2 of x", "3 of x"...."x of x".

"Sheet1" Col "S" holds the x-numerical value. Copy col "B" through "AJ" in each row with value and paste in "sheet3".

I have used some code found in stack overflow at "[Copy Row X amount of times based on cell value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35625405/copy-row-x-amount-of-times-based-on-cell-value)", but need it to change value of "S" in each added row.

```
Sub Sample()
Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
Dim lRow_I As Long, lRow_O As Long, i As Long, j As Long

'~~> Set your input and output sheets
Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

'~~> Output row
lRow_O = wsO.Range("B" & wsO.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

With wsI
    '~~> Get last row of input sheet
    lRow_I = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    '~~> Loop through the rows
    For i = 2 To lRow_I
        '~~> This will loop the number of time required
        '~~> i.e the number present in cell S
        For j = 1 To Val(Trim(.Range("S" & i).Value))
            '~~> This copies
            .Rows(i).Copy wsO.Rows(lRow_O)
            '~~> Get the next output row
            lRow_O = wsO.Range("B" & wsO.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Next j
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

I expect each row on sheet 1 to be on sheet 3 the amount of times cell "S" ("S"= numerical digit between 1-15) in that row's value is. Then each new line added will have "S" value "1 of S", "2 of S", and so on to "S of S".

Comment: So, do you want to paste the data or fill it with `x of y`?

Comment: So I want to copy the rows in sheet 1 and past them in new rows on sheet 3. I want to past the original row into multiple new rows the quantity of rows is determined by the value of cell "S". If there is a quantity of "2" in "S", then the row copies 2 times and adding into the new Row's "S" cell 1 of 2 and 2 of 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Sample()

    Dim wsI As Worksheet, wsO As Worksheet
    Dim lRow_I As Long, lRow_O As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Dim rw As Range, n As Long

    Set wsI = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsO = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")

    lRow_O = wsO.Range("B" & wsO.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    lRow_I = wsI.Range("B" & wsI.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lRow_I

        Set rw = wsI.Rows(i)
        n = Val(Trim(rw.Range("S1").Value))

        rw.Copy wsO.Rows(lRow_O).Resize(n) 'makes n copies of the row

        'add the "x of n" values
        wsO.Cells(lRow_O, "S").Resize(n, 1).Value = Evaluate("=ROW(1:" & n & ") & "" of " & n & """")

        'or alternatively / less complex...
        for j = 1 to n
            wsO.Cells(lRow_O, "S").Offset(j-1, 0).Value = j & " of " & n
        next j

        lRow_O = lRow_O + n

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. Works great. Thank you.